# MongoDB, Getting Started and Connecting with Compass

Tags: connectivity, remote, mongodb-3.6

I'm trying to connect to my mongoDB running as a service on my rPi3B+, using openSuse Tumbleweed 64bit, mongo version 3.6.2, from my laptop sharing the same LAN/Wifi (pi on LAN & laptop on Wifi).

I completed this install guide(https://www.osradar.com/install-mongodb-opensuse-15/) directly after a fresh install of the rPi3 JeOS image provided here: https://en.opensuse.org/HCL:Raspberry_Pi3

Now when I tried to connect to the db service using compass using the same IP I used to connect to the Pi over ssh, and the standard port of 27017. It then reports "MongoDB not running on the provided host and port".

However, I have the shell running on the Pi at the same time, and when I exit the shell so that compass is the only client attempting a connection. When I run `sudo systemctl status mongodb` the service is active.

When I run `netstat -lntu` I get the following output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:27017               :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 192.168.1.163:123       0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 fe80::ba27:ebff:feb:123 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*
```

When I ping the Pi's IP address using the local IP I get the expected returns showing that it is reachable.

Are there some settings I need to change from within the shell to make it reachable by Compass?

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty, I guess this was a noob question.

Answers can be found here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739166/could-not-connect-to-mongodb-on-the-provided-host-and-port#49220957

Pretty sure many of their different methods would work. For some reason `mongo --bind_ip_all` didn't work for me and seems like the simplest. I think it has something to do with openSuse's arm version doesn't use `mongod` and instead just `mongo`.

What worked for me was going into my '/etc/mongodb.conf' file and changing the boundIP from `127.0.0.1,::1` to `0.0.0.0,::1`

Not to sure what the `::1` is for but I can connect to the db with compass now.